# React do I have to rerender parent in order to rerender children?

Tags: reactjs, redux, immutable.js

I have a table component, with list of items.
By changing an item in the list, I see that whole table is rerender.
I tried to put shouldComponentUpdate, and by returning false I see that the Row components are not rerendered.
Do I have to rerender the parent in order to rerender child components?

Comment: Re-rendering in the UI is not the same as the render method being called. Which is it for the parent? It could be "rendering" but no DOM changes are actually made if there are no differences.

Comment: Child components are affected by the data passed by your parent component. Curious. Why did you have to prevent the rerendering on your parent component?

Answer (score 1):

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate

> Returning false does not prevent child components from re-rendering when their state changes.

If the data in the child is passed as a property from the parent, then yes, you will have to rerender the parent to rerender the child. The reason for this is that if your child is reliant on props, and the parent does not render, then those props are never changed for the child as it only receives changed props when the parent renders and gives it new ones based on its own state or props. I suspect this is your problem. Rerendering the parent is not usually a performance problem in React.

If the children had their own state that was changing then not rerendering the parent would be ok. Another option if you are using a state container is to `connect` the children directly to the state and then their props get updated when the state container updates the relevant state, but that is somewhat beyond the scope of this question.

In general, it is best not to use `shouldComponentUpdate` unless performance demands it and then only with very careful consideration.